# jquery select check box selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery

`<form id="myform">`

`<input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' value='1'>`

`<input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' checked='true' value='2' >`

`<input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' value='3' >`

`<input type='checkbox' name='foo[]' checked='true' value='4' >`

`</form>`

now using jquery, i need to get selected values of name foo[].

Also i need to pass these as an array to a php file i.e foo = array(2,4)

Comment: you want to send the data via AJAX or using the form's submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
          arr[]=$(this).val();
   });
```

to get the values of each element then covert it to json using

```
  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var val_arr = [];
var arr = $('input[name="foo[]"]:checked');
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
val_arr.push(arr[i].value);
}
console.log(val_arr);
```

Comment: i want is using jquery, not by normal html.
Also i dont get use of "foo[]"

Comment: @chicharito for your kind information, its not html markup. its vanilla javascript code. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitForm() {
  var form = $('#myform');
  form.submit(function(){ // configure onsubmit event
    form.attr({'method': 'post'}); // set form method to post
    form.attr({'action': 'yourphpfile.php'}); // set file to receive form data
  });
  form.submit(); // submit the form
}
```

on the php file you can view the contents in $_POST:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
var array = new Array();
$('input[name="foo[]"]:checked').each(function(i,el){
        array.push($(el).val());
});
for(var i in array){
   alert("value=="+array[i]);
}
```

If need you can Read [How to check a checkbox is checked using jQuery Post](http://antguider.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-check-checkbox-is-checked-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
var checkedValues = [];
var checkedElems= $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

$.each(checkedElems, function(index, element){
   checkedValues.push($(element).val());
});

$.post(
    "something.php",
    {
       arrayOfValues: JSON.stringify(checkedValues),
       ........
    },
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
       alert("Success!");
    }
);
```